# Different behavior CURL vs http.get - CORS

Tags: http, angular, cors

So, I am really getting annoyed at this:

Command line:

```
$ curl -X GET "cloudant/url" --header "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzcw==" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
{ "response": "OK" }
```

With Angular 2 http module (inside of an injectable service):

```
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzcw=="); 
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

this.http.get("cloudant/url", { method: "GET", headers: headers });
```

> 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

I should not, nor need to, care about the server configuration. I want to emit a GET request to the server, and any CORS client-sided security concerns are none of my business.

Can I make `Http` behave like curl in this particular regard?

Comment: Well, CORS is a thing, and whether it's of your business or not, the browser does implement CORS, because it's a required security feature of browsers. You can write your own browser without CORS, if you really want to. Or you can acknowledge the fact that CORS exist, and fix the server. BTW, sending a content-type header with a GET request doesn't make much sense: GET requests don't have a body, so the content type is irrelevant.

Comment: I want the request to start from my server, not from my browser. How can I do that? This piece of code is part of a service. I didn't expect that service to run from the client

Comment: Well Angular applications run in the browser. It's a frontend framework. If you want the request to be sent from your server, then use whatever your server technology is to send the request (PHP? Java? NodeJS? Ruby? .Net?)

Comment: I am using ng serve to serve the application. I assumed that would take care of it

Comment: ng serve just starts a development server that only serves the static files generated for the frontend of your application. You still need a server to host your server-side logic (the REST services, access to your database, requests from the server to external services, etc.). The ng server server can act as a proxy to your actual REST server though: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Okay thanks for your input, I understand my mistake

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what CORS is intended to do. It prevents you from making cross origin requests from your browser unless the server is set up to specifically allow it. I understand your frustration, but there is no workaround for this.

You're mistaken in thinking that CORS is simply a client side security concern. It takes a well configured server coupled with a well designed front end app to build something really great. And you *should* care about the server configuration as much as it ensures that you are able to deliver a responsive and snappy front end experience. If any website in the world could just start hitting this API there would be all kinds of additional security and performance concerns for the backend.

Comment: But it's not happening from my browser - well, I didn't expect this to happen from my browser... Maybe this  is where I am misunderstanding something? And yes, I know what's cors...

Comment: What do you mean that it's not happening in the browser? That's where your Angular app runs. Unless you're doing something with Angular Universal on the server side?

Comment: I thought this framework was a front/back end abstraction in fact, and that some of the code would run on the server. I don't handle the server myself, ng serve does it,  which is why I thought this.

Comment: Angular *can* be run on the server using Angular Universal https://github.com/angular/universal but doesn't sound like that's what you're doing. Angular CLI is hosting a local development server for the purposes of doing live reload, asset bundling and minification, tree shaking, etc. But your angular app runs in the browser so you're bound by CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead:

```
  return fetch(url, { method: "GET" }).then(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
```

...

```
  private extractData(res: Response): Promise<CloudantCheckStatisticsRowMapping> {
    let p = res.json();
    return p.then(function(body: any) {
        console.log("Found " + body.total_rows + " records; last one is the one we need.");
        return body.rows[0].doc;
    });
  }
```

It seems it's not bothered by the CORS.

[image]

Comment: @Alex yeah, it's just for a poc. Real production environment will fix the cors in the first place I'm not worried.

Comment: In fact, I pasted the browser compatibility sheet, it's not too bad